# UIScrollView velocity 0 while decelerating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to detect the user scroll direction to prevent wrong swipe. I use this following code

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

        CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer velocityInView:self];


            if (fabs(velocity.y) * 2 < fabs(velocity.x))
            {
                //scroll LEFT or RIGHT 
                return NO;
            }
            else
            {
                //scroll UP or DOWN 
            }


         return YES;
}
```

it works in most case, **except if the user scroll while the scrollview is decelerating**, then the velocity factor is null, and i can't calculate the scroll direction.

**EDIT 1**

similar problem :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393092/3746376)

Comment: set the contentsize to width of screen and it won't scroll to left to right

Comment: i use a vertical collectionView inside an horizontal pageViewController. When the user scroll up/down the collectionView, i need to prevent ambigus left/right swipe. it works except when the collectionView is decelerating.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution will be to detect the scroll direction directly on the `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073028/2846494)

Comment: i need to know the direction inside the 
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` method to block any wrong gestures